# Why does the where() method run SQL queries after all nested relations are eager-loaded?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, eager-loading, rails-postgresql

In my controller method for the the index view I have the following line.

```
@students_instance = Student.includes(:memo_tests => {:memo_target => :memo_level})
```

So for each `Student` I eager-load all necessary info.

Later on in a `.map` block, I call the `.where()` method on one of the relations as shown below.

```
@all_students = @students_instance.map do |student|

...

last_pass = student.memo_tests.where(:result => true).last.created_at.utc
difference_in_weeks = ((last_pass.to_i - current_date.to_i) / 1.week).round

...

end
```

**This leads to a single SQL query for each `student`.** And since I have over 300+ students, leads to very slow load times and over 300+ SQL queries.

Am I right in thinking that this is caused by the `.where()` method. I think this because I have checked everything else and these are the two lines that cause all of the queries.

**More importantly, is there a better way to do this that reduces these queries to a single query?**

Comment: So you want to get a last passed memo_test for each student?

Comment: Thing is this query will be quite complicated and I'm not even sure if it's possible to do in ActiveRecord. Maybe you will have to go for something like sequel or write sql yourself

Comment: Not exactly, I already have access to each students' `memo_tests` without running a query. I want to run the `.where` method, without using a SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you ask `where`, the statement is translated to a query. Normally, the result should be sql-cached...

Anyway, in order to be sure, you can instead add programming logic to your statement. That way, you are not requesting a **NEW** sql statement.

```
last_pass = student.memo_tests.map {|m| m.created_at if m.result}.compact.sort.last
```

**EDIT**
I see the OP's question does not require sorting... So, leaving the sorting out:

```
last_pass = student.memo_tests.map {|m| m.created_at if m.result}.compact.last
```

`compact` is required to remove nil results from the array.

Comment: This solution might be even slower that original.

Comment: How? If there is SQL, there will either be many or few results... Many results, slow sql, slower sorting... Few results, fast sql, fast sorting... No SQL... slower???

Comment: In original answer you did map compact and sort on a collection of unspecified length. It is rarely faster than sql, and however unpopular with Rails folks, a pure sql solution is the best way to go here.

Comment: Yes, it was a hasty answer I admit...  I've noticed however many times that pure sql is faster only if you use small number of queries. Large number of queries means many disk iops, while sorting and mapping is pure cpu and ram...

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Why do you think it ran a query for that?

Comment: Not 100% sure,  but I think that adding a `where()` method introduces a new SQL statement,  that is not cached.. So, the query had to be performed anew.